# How do you bypass static method calls?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have this line which is interferring in a unit test:

```
OtherClass.staticMethodThatWillErrorIfCalled().isAvailable();
```

If it wasn't static I could just mock OtherClass and then do this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(mockedOtherClass).staticMethodThatWillErrorIfCalled();
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(mockedOtherClass).isGuiMode();
```

and the fact that it will error if called makes my attempts at using powermockito futile.

I'm not sure how I can do this. All I want to do is skip over this line (it's an if check) and continue on as if it had returned true. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please post more information, the whole unit test will be a good start.
Is static method in class being tested?

Comment: Mock it. You *can* mock statics.

Comment: @AlexBuyny i'm just executing a method in ClassToBeTested, but that method has the if check that I talk about which will call that static method that throws an error. I don't care about testing the static method or anything else in OtherClass I just want to get a true value returned so that I can execute and test a method in ClassToBeTested

Comment: @DaveNewton yes but because it is static it will call the method and so the error will be thrown. I want to skip over the method.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10359/unit-testing-legacy-code-with-static-classes)
There are some approaches how to deal with statics in this article

Comment: I cannot make changes to either class, only to the unit test class

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) may help?

Comment: I've gone through that already, it also calls the static method.

Comment: ... You can mock static methods. I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: the issue is that the static method is being called, say I have a sysout in the method, it will still display that message, which I don't want, I want to completely skip over it so the sysout is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

I would require more info to give a more specific answer but this is what I am thinking...

First tell PowerMockito that you will be mocking a static method in OtherClass.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(OtherClass.class)
```

These are class level annotations that go on your unit testing class.

Then mock what to do when that method is called.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(OtherClass.class);
Mockito.when(OtherClass.isAvailable()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Do this in your `@Before` method on your unit testing.